# Symfony 1.4 conditional validation

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a `Profile` form that inherits from `sfGuardRegisterForm`

I have these fields:

```
$this->useFields(
    array('first_name', 
          'last_name',
          'email_address',
          'country',
          'language',
          'current_password',
          'new_password',
          'password_again',
    )
);
```

Required fields are:

`email_address`, `country` and `language`

And the conditions are:

1. If the `email_address` is not equal with the current `email_address`
   then check if it's **unique** then save it
2. If the `current_password` is the actual password of the user then verify if `new_password` and `password_again` are equals and verify that the `new_password` is not equal to the actual password of the user

I just can't figure out in how implement this

**EDIT**

Thanks **1ed** your example works but the problem is that I load the user Profile and I fill the fields: `'first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'country', 'language'` with the actual logged user so the `email_address` field will show the email address:

```
//...
$this->widgetSchema['email_address']->setDefault($this->_user->getEmailAddress());
//...
```

If the user dont change the email it will always show this message:

> An object with the same "email_address" already exist.

I just want to skip that

Also this `$this->getObject()->checkPassword()` does not works, always show this message:

> Incorrect current password.

I use:

> $this->_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();

To get actual user profile

**EDIT2**

Thanks again **1ed**

This is very weird and I'm getting frustated, this is the situation

1. I have a "workaround" for this but it does not follow the standard, I can make it works but using `sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();` and it will be more unnecesary code
2. If I use `new ProfileForm($user)` automatically fills all the fields, that's very good **but** I can't `setDefault()` I can't set `null` or `empty` any field so I can't use `doUpdateObject()` because this function only works when the current data is updated, also I have tested overriding `bind()`, `save()` etc. without results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

email_address uniqueness: you should set `unique: true` in schema, in `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` that's the case by default, so in `BasesfGuardUserForm` you should see a unique validator already: `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'sfGuardUser', 'column' => array('email_address'))`

current_password: you should create a callback type post validator for this

```
// in sfGuardRegisterForm::configure()

// these fields can be blank
$this->getValidator('current_password')->setOption('required', false);
$this->getValidator('new_password')->setOption('required', false);
$this->getValidator('password_again')->setOption('required', false);

// check the current password (this validator is not `required` by default)
$this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array(
  'callback' => array($this, 'checkPassword'),
), array(
  'invalid' => 'Incorrect current password.'
)));

// add this method to the same form class
public function checkPassword(sfValidatorBase $validator, array $values, array $arguments)
{
  // if a new password is given check whether the old one is correct or not and rise an error if not correct
  if(0 != strlen($values['new_password']) && !$this->getObject()->checkPassword($values['current_password']))
  {
    throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array(
      'current_password' => new sfValidatorError($validator, 'invalid')
    ));
  }

  return $values;
}
```

Alternatively you can create a custom post validator, but I think it's not necessary.

**EDIT:**

If you would like to display empty email address just like the password fields add these to your form class:

```
// at form load remove the default value
protected function updateDefaultsFromObject()
{
  parent::updateDefaultsFromObject();

  if (isset($this['email_address']))
  {
    $this->setDefault('email_address', '');
  }
}

// before save remove empty email address
protected function doUpdateObject($values)
{
  if (isset($values['email_address']) && 0 == strlen($values['email_address']))
  {
    unset($values['email_address']);
  }

  parent::doUpdateObject($values);
}
```

Comment: I think the validators dont`t works because you don't set the underlying user object. And this `$this->_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();` is not good idea, always try avoid using sfContext if it's possible. In the action, where you create the form, you should get the user object and pass it to the form and all values will be filled in based on the user. `$user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser(); $this->form = new ProfileForm($user);`. The `setDefault()` calls are not required.

Comment: One mote thing... the `sfValidatorSchemaCompare` validator is not required because it is already in the `BasesfGuardUserAdminForm` so I removed that.

Comment: you right, I have changed `$this->form = new ProfileForm($this->getUser()->getGuardUser());` and it works and I'm thinking in not show the email address and put it `required = false`

Comment: I've just fixed the `chackPassword()` for the "0" input, please update your code and sorry for that.

Comment: The password field is a special one because if you give an empty password nothing happens, but if you post your form with an empty email the former email will be deleted from the database. If you really would like to show an empty email field and modify the database just if the email changes take a look my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry my mistake again... you should use`updateDefaultsFromObject()`... maybe I should sleep a bit :)

Comment: It works but not as **must be**, if the user write the same email it will show the message that the email is already used.. well at least I dont have to write more unnecesary code.. thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and explain this in methodical terms instead of giving you a big block of code....
So first, you want to **if (email_addr != current_email)** and if that's true, go on to do
**if (new_pass != current_pass)** then follow on to make sure **if (new_pass == new_pass_again)**
Inside all of these IFs, you can return a true/false or some kind of flag, or  just *//do code* inside the brackets :p

**EDIT:** encase these IFs in: **if (country != NULL && language != NULL && email_addr != NULL)**

Comment: Thanks I have done that, the problem that I'm facing now it's to check if the **email_address** != **actual_email** and check if the email its unique in the database

Comment: Well for that you'd need to get every email in the DB and put them into an array, then do a foreach() and compare them, then return if it's true or not. & for the current email just go through the DB and select users USERNAME and go through users indexes, get the current_email, and compare it. Logic like this can be confusing, and I don't work with DBs a lot but if you search on Google something like _How to search all the indexes of a db in php mysql/sqlite_ you should come up with somethin'